# Getting stuck on DNS configurations for routing external domains to my internal Kubernetes cluster (Traefik)

Tags: networking, dns, kubernetes

I have DNS entries in CloudFlare set to my current home IP (I have Dynamic DNS setup).

```
who.willkara.com > IP
```

Internally, I have a PiHole server handling DNS and actually have that working.The PiHole is set as the DNS server for the DHCP and Internet:

[image: Internet DNS Setup for Unifi Controller]
[image: DHCP DNS Settings for Unifi Controller]

If I set the DNS for the Traefik routing to `who.willkara` and then add the proper DNS CNAME entry for PiHole `traefik.willkara` it properly routes internally.

`who.willkara` > `traefik.willkara` will properly render in my browser.

But, for some reason I can't get the full routing to work externally. I just turned off SSL in CloudFlare to ensure the connections work before I attempt Let's Encrypt, but it just defaults to an NGINX Landing Page (still trying to find what server that's on).

`http://who.willkara.com/ >  Random NGINX Landing Page`

My guess is that somewhere the DNS request is getting lost between my router (UniFi USG) and the internal DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** It was DNS

-__-

Had an old record and port-forwarding rule that was confusing the resolution.